# Is it possible to create a calulated column on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that show the stats of each step of my item. It Looks like this:

```
ITEM    STEP_1    STEP_2    STEP_3    STEP_4    STEP_5
-----  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------
1        OK        NOK        OK        NOK    IN ANALYSIS
2        OK        OK         OK        OK     N/A
3        NOK       NOK        NOK       NOK    NOK
```

What I want to do is create a View with a new column of progress. Like this:

```
ITEM    STEP_1    STEP_2    STEP_3    STEP_4    STEP_5       Progress
-----  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------     -----------
1        OK        NOK        OK        NOK    ANALYSIS        40%
2        OK        OK         OK        OK     N/A             100%
3        NOK       NOK        NOK       NOK    NOK              0%
```

The percentage value is found by summing every step that has "OK" or "N/A" in it and dividing by the total number of steps (in this case 5).

Is is possible to do this?

Edit 1.:

Like this?

```
ITEM    STEPs     STATUS 
-----  --------  --------
1       Step_1     OK
1       Step_2     NOK
1       Step_3     NOK
1       Step_4     ANALYSIS
1       Step_5     OK
```

Edit.2:

Here is a simplified version of how I'm doing the normalization:

```
SELECT

T.*

FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT
    ITEM_ID,

      (SELECT FINAL_STATUS
      FROM book_new b
      WHERE a.ITEM_ID        = b.ITEM_ID
      AND b.STEPS        = 'STEP_1'
      ) AS STEP_1 ,

      (SELECT FINAL_STATUS
      FROM book_new b
      WHERE a.ITEM_ID        = b.ITEM_ID
      AND b.STEPS        = 'STEP_2'
      ) AS STEP_2 ,

      (SELECT FINAL_STATUS
      FROM book_new b
      WHERE a.ITEM_ID        = b.ITEM_ID
      AND b.STEPS        = 'STEP_3'
      AND ROWNUM = 1
      ) AS STEP_3 ,

      (SELECT FINAL_STATUS
      FROM book_new b
      WHERE a.ITEM_ID        = b.ITEM_ID
      AND b.STEPS        = 'STEP_4'
      AND ROWNUM = 1
      ) AS STEP_4 ,

      (SELECT FINAL_STATUS
      FROM book_new b
      WHERE a.ITEM_ID        = b.ITEM_ID
      AND b.STEPS        = 'STEP_5'
      AND ROWNUM = 1
      ) AS STEP_5

FROM book_new A

    ) T
```

Comment: This is a denormalized design.  You ought to consider a one to many relationship between ITEM and STEP tables.

Comment: Yes, it's possible - even straightforward, though it would be easier if the data was denormalised. Have you tried, and if so what problems did you have?

Comment: In 11g+, you can a virtual column.  In earlier versions, you can use a view.

Comment: Sorry about the newb question but what do you guys mean by denormalizing the data?

Comment: Is it something like the Edit 1?

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso yes - although the `step` column could probably just be a number. If you need to query/display data in the way you originally showed you could [pivot](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG0209); though you'd still need to know the maximum number of steps, so it's something the application might do if that is variable.

Comment: @AlexPoole Alright. Actually the table I am working on is like the Edit 1 I just showed. I thought the normalized version would be better for this kind of approach. I also have the exact number of steps which is 76. So, how can I create the progress column with the denormalized table?

Comment: Something like `count(case when status = 'OK' then status end)/0.75`, which could handle a variable number of steps too. But without seeing how you're getting to the normalized version, exactly how that fits in to your view definition isn't clear - might need an analytic/windowed count, for instance.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just added an Edit 2 with the Query i'm using to create the normalized version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with your denormalised data, you can find the percentage of steps for each item that are 'OK' with an analytic count query:

```
select item_id, steps, final_status,
  100 * count(case when final_status in ('OK', 'N/A') then final_status end)
    over (partition by item_id) -- analytic function with windowing clause
  / count(steps) over (partition by item_id) as percent_ok
from book_new
order by item_id, steps;

   ITEM_ID STEPS  FINAL_ST PERCENT_OK
---------- ------ -------- ----------
         1 STEP_1 OK               40
         1 STEP_2 NOK              40
         1 STEP_3 NOK              40
         1 STEP_4 ANALYSIS         40
         1 STEP_5 OK               40
         2 STEP_1 OK               100

...
```

You can then pivot that into the tabular format you want; on 11gR2 or higher you can use the built-pivot operator:

```
select item_id, a_step as step_1, b_step as step_2, c_step as step_3,
  d_step as step_4, e_step as step_5, percent_ok || '%' as progress
from (
  select item_id, steps, final_status,
    100 * count(case when final_status in ('OK', 'N/A') then final_status end)
      over (partition by item_id)
    / count(steps) over (partition by item_id) as percent_ok
  from book_new
)
pivot (max(final_status) as step for (steps) in ('STEP_1' as a, 'STEP_2' as b,
  'STEP_3' as c, 'STEP_4' as d, 'STEP_5' as e))
order by item_id;

   ITEM_ID STEP_1   STEP_2   STEP_3   STEP_4   STEP_5   PROGRESS                  
---------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------------------------
         1 OK       NOK      NOK      ANALYSIS OK       40%                       
         2 OK       OK       OK       OK       N/A      100%                       
         3 NOK      NOK      NOK      NOK      NOK      0%
```

In earlier versions you can manually pivot the data with an aggregate function over a case expression:

```
select item_id,
  max(case when steps = 'STEP_1' then final_status end) as step_1,
  max(case when steps = 'STEP_2' then final_status end) as step_2,
  max(case when steps = 'STEP_3' then final_status end) as step_3,
  max(case when steps = 'STEP_4' then final_status end) as step_4,
  max(case when steps = 'STEP_5' then final_status end) as step_5,
  percent_ok || '%' as progress
from (
  select item_id, steps, final_status,
    100 * count(case when final_status in ('OK', 'N/A') then final_status end)
      over (partition by item_id)
    / count(steps) over (partition by item_id) as percent_ok
  from book_new
)
group by item_id, percent_ok
order by item_id;
```

which gets the same result (and is what 11g does under the hood anyway).

Your approach of using subqueries isn't going to be terribly efficient, since you're querying the same table multiple times. However, with that approach you could still use @Allan's answer - just change the outer `SELECT T.* FROM` to list the columns and do the calculation in the same way.

You can read more about [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), and [pivoting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG0209), in the documentation.

---

Incidentally, you could also slightly change the way you calculate the progress. If a step is N/A then it might not make sense to count it at all; you could instead change the inner query to ignore those, just for the purposes of counting:

```
  select item_id, steps, final_status,
    100 * count(case when final_status = 'OK' then final_status end)
      over (partition by item_id)
    / count(case when final_status != 'N/A' then final_status end)
      over (partition by item_id) as percent_ok
  from book_new
```

That doesn't make any difference with your sample data, but if you had an item with N/A and others with anything except OK then the percentage would go up. That might not be what you want, but it's an option...

Comment: Thx a lot! It worked! BTW, didn't know about that pivot function. Can I use it to create a view?

Comment: Yes, you can; if you really have 75 steps you may find the `max(case)` version easier to create andmanage though.

Answer (score 1):

Just define the calculation you want to use and include an alias:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW your_view AS
   SELECT item,
          step_1,
          step_2,
          step_3,
          step_4,
          step_5,
               (  CASE WHEN step_1 IN ('OK', 'N/A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN step_2 IN ('OK', 'N/A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN step_3 IN ('OK', 'N/A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN step_4 IN ('OK', 'N/A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                + CASE WHEN step_5 IN ('OK', 'N/A') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             / 5
             * 100
          || '%'
             AS progress
   FROM   your_table
```

If you want the calculation to change dynamically based on the number of `step` columns, you're out of luck. RDBMS are generally not designed to handle dynamic columns.

Also, as duffymo pointed out, this would be substantially easier in a properly normalized design. That would also allow you to adjust the number of steps dynamically.